# Text of JMenu not centered

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I extends `BasicMenuUI`, and overide `getPreferredSize(JComponent c)`, and as a result the text of the `JMenu` is not centered anymore.

I tried to fix it using the several `setAlignment` methods but nothing work.

I would like to have the same size for all menus, and text centered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant [`getPreferredSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicMenuItemUI.html#getPreferredSize%28javax.swing.JComponent%29), inherited from `BasicMenuItemUI`, is supposed to be "appropriate for the look and feel." Each L&F uses decorations of a different size. If you're not doing that, you should return `null` and specify "the component's layout manager."

Naturally, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would help.

Addendum:

> the text of the JMenu is not centered anymore.

I don't think it was ever centered, but you can move the `textRect` if desired.

[image]

```
class CustomMenuUI extends BasicMenuUI {

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new CustomMenuUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintText(Graphics g, JMenuItem menuItem,
            Rectangle textRect, String text) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        int w2 = menuItem.getBounds().width / 2;
        textRect.translate(w2 - textRect.width / 2, 0);
        super.paintText(g, menuItem, textRect, text);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        return new Dimension(80, 32);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.put("MenuUI", "testmenuui.CustomMenuUI");
                    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    createAndShowGui();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menuTest1 = new JMenu("Menu1");

        JMenu menuTest2 = new JMenu("Menu2");

        menuBar.add(menuTest1);
        menuBar.add(menuTest2);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CustomMenuUI extends BasicMenuUI {

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new CustomMenuUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBackground(Graphics g, JMenuItem menuItem, Color bgColor) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        super.paintBackground(g, menuItem, bgColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintText(Graphics g, JMenuItem menuItem, Rectangle textRect, String text) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        super.paintText(g, menuItem, textRect, text);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect. This should be an update to you question.